# continue playing audio when iphone/device goes sleep or locked

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, core-audio, background-audio

I am using the following code to keep playing audio when iPhone/iPod goes sleep or locked.

```
mv = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl/myMusic.mp3"]];
mv.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeUnknown;
[self.view addSubview:mv.view];
[mv play];

UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof (sessionCategory), &sessionCategory); AudioSessionSetActive(true);
```

By using this code my device is not going into sleep mode but what i want is, device should go in sleep mode but audio should not stop playing.
I have added `Required background modes`and `App plays audio` in my `info.plist` file.

Please suggest me where am I wrong? Why the device is not going into sleep mode/locked?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7545093/1557663

Answer (score 2):

Use this code in viewdidload:

```
NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
NSError *activationErr  = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &setCategoryErr];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &activationErr];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier newTaskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
newTaskId = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:NULL];
```

It is working fine for me.

Comment: Tried it. Again app is not going into sleep mode.. I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: you have added Required background modes and App plays audio in my info.plist file?

Comment: Yes. I have added all these things.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, include these frameworks to your project: AudioToolbox, CoreAudio, MediaPlayer and AVFoundation. Import them all to the viewController where your player will be placed. After you allocated and started playing the audio, insert the following code:

```
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof (sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);
AudioSessionSetActive(true);
```

And finally, go to your app Info.plist file and add a row named UIBackgroundModes. The new row will be an array and will contain 1 item, the item 0. To this you just set the value as audio. And you're done! Enjoy you're background audio playing app!

hope it helps. happy coding :)

Comment: I already tried it. The only problem is device not going into sleep mode.

Comment: @Anshuk I think the code you provided, will make the device awake till the app is on foreground.